# Does firebase phone authentication support all mobile operators of supported country?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

My country (Kazakhstan) supported by firebase phone authentication and I recieve OTP codes correct to mobile phones starts with **+7701**, **+7705**, **+7707**.  But I can't recieve OTPs for phone numbers starting with **+7708** which is also popular in Kazakhstan.  Is there some limitations for certain mobile operators or something?

Comment: Do the phone numbers with +7708 belong to the same Telecom Provider?

Comment: This is not a general programming question that someone here is likely to be able to answer. If you're having problem with the delivery of SMS messages to a specific provider, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to Firebase yes, it should be supported:

https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#phone-auth-countries

But I had the same problem once in Mexico, I found the root cause and the issue was the Telecom provider, it was detecting those specific SMS as "not trust source", so I never was able to do it with that specific provider. I think that the issue is solved now, but you may try to also consider that option.